# Solr : How to Index a field in document as json field?

Tags: java, json, solr, solrj

I know we can index a document as json but I want to index a field inside my document as json.

e.g.

```
{
            id:"Person1",
            name:"bob",
            associatedCompanies:[
                                 {
                                     companyName:"apple",
                                     companyId:"c1"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     companyName:"google",
                                     companyId:"c2"
                                 }
                             ]
}
```

I can have associatedCompanies field as an array by declaring it as multiValued in schema. But how can I add company element as json?

I don't think [the parent-child example](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) applies here since in this use case, the json element which is nested is not exactly same as the document. I just want to add some json element in my document.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be indexed? And how to query with such index? Is it possible to do query like below..

```
id:person AND name:bob AND associatedCompanies:[{
                                     companyName:"apple",
                                     companyId:"c1"
                                 }]
```

or

```
id:person AND name:bob AND associatedCompanies:[{
                                         companyName:"apple"
                                     }]
```

In second query, will I get the response with the document having apple company?

Answer (score 1):

Try out : [Solr Nested Documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments)
and the [Block Join Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers)

Comment: I've used this [solr-nested-object](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/#Lucene_Index_Representation) tutorial as well to do some tests.Maybe it can be of help for you as well.